# Network monitoring tool- open source

Tags: linux, open-source, software-development, monitoring, network-monitor

I have a standalone application which is running in a box(GCP virtual box). I need to check whether the box is alive or not(running or not). I need a centralised monitoring machine which will run as a daemon and get status of my box every time. If there is no response from the box, Then the centralised machine should send an email notification to the system admin. It should also monitor the network status, network slow or not. So, What best open source monitoring tool helps my requirement.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One that you may wish to look at is [GRR Rapid Response](https://github.com/google/grr) which is an incident response framework focused on remote live forensics.

It consists of a python agent (client) that is installed on target systems, and python server infrastructure that can manage and talk to the agent.

The client is cross platform, *Linux, Windows & OS-X* but the server is normally either a Docker image or a linux box with Ubuntu Xenial Server 64-bit.

Allows a lot of monitoring, diagnostics & remote deployment.

Open Source as requested.